# Keep line breaks when printing custom plain text textarea field

Tags: 7

I'm using Drupal 7. I'm printing out a custom plain text textarea field in the node template using the following code:

```
print ($taxonomy_term->field_address['und'][0]['value']);
```

However, when I print it out I lose all the line breaks.  Is there a way I can keep the line breaks in when I print out the field value?

I have already changed the plain text format to add "limit allowed HTML tags" rule for `<a> <br> <p>`, and removed the "display any HTML as plain text" rule.

Many thanks,

Ben

Answer (score 4):

I worked it out. I just needed to use the following code:

```
print nl2br($taxonomy_term->field_address['und'][0]['value']);
```

This uses the print nl2br function to convert line breaks to `<br>` tags.